# API or Method to Replace all non-latin-1 characters

Tags: java, utf-8, replace, latin1

I'm dealing with a 3rd party API / Web Service and they only allow latin-1 character set in their XML.  Is there an existing API / method that will find and replace all non-latin-1 characters in a String?

For example: Kévin

Is there anyway to make that Kevin?

Comment: So you don't want `K&#233;vin`, to remove them from the byte stream (as you open it in a simple text editor), but actually remove them from the XMl infoset (as an XML parser reads it to an application) as well?

Comment: é is defined in latin-1 (code point 233). Are you sure it's not ASCII you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ICU4J,

```
public String removeAccents(String text) {
    return Normalizer.decompose(text, false, 0)
                 .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

I found this example at http://glaforge.appspot.com/article/how-to-remove-accents-from-a-string

In java 1.6 the necessary normalizer might be built-in.

Comment: A very good first start, at least for the given example. However there are no guarantees that the result will be ASCII-only, as there are Unicode codepoints which do not decompose into an ASCII character and combining diacritics.

Comment: If you really want to cope with all the obscure cases, you're going to have to write code. Possibly an ICU4J transcoder object. There's nothing I know of that has all the wierd possibility, like turning ℃
DEGREE CELSIUS into C, or Ł
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L WITH STROKE to L.

Comment: Or detect unconvertible codepoints and respond appropriately, by removing them, aborting the operation, asking the user or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across lots of posts on how to remove **all** accents. This (old!) post covers my use case, so I'll share my solution here. In my case, I only want to replace characters not present in the ISO-8859-1 charset. The use case is: read a UTF-8 file, and write it to a ISO-8859-1 file, while retaining as many of the special characters as possible (but prevent UnmappableCharacterException).

```
@Test
void proofOfConcept() {
    final String input = "Bełchatöw";
    final String expected = "Belchatöw";
    final String actual = MyMapper.utf8ToLatin1(input);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

**Normalizer** seems interesting, but I only found ways to remove all accents.

```
public static String utf8ToLatin1(final String input) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

Weirdly, the above code not only fails, but with

```
expected: <Belchatöw> but was: <Bełchatow>
```

**CharsetEncoder** seems interesting, but it appears I can only set a static "replacement" character (actually: byte array), so all unmappable characters become '?' or similar

```
public static String utf8ToLatin1(final String input) throws CharacterCodingException {
    final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.newEncoder()
        .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
        .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
        .replaceWith(new byte[] { (byte) '?' })
        .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(input));
    return new String(byteBuffer.array(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
}
```

Fails with

```
expected: <Belchatöw> but was: <Be?chatöw>
```

My final solution is thus:

```
public static String utf8ToLatin1(final String input) {
    final Map<String, String> characterMap = new HashMap<>();
    characterMap.put("ł", "l");
    characterMap.put("Ł", "L");
    characterMap.put("œ", "ö");
    final StringBuffer resultBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{InBasic_Latin}\\p{InLatin-1Supplement}]").matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(resultBuffer,
            characterMap.computeIfAbsent(matcher.group(),
                s -> Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(resultBuffer);
    return resultBuffer.toString();
}
```

A few points:

1. The `characterMap` needs to be extended to your needs. The `Normalizer` is useful for accented characters, but you might have others. Also, extract `characterMap` out (beware that computeIfAbsent updates the map, beware of concurrency!)
2. Pattern.compile() shouldn't be called repeatedly, extract that out to a static